# How to programmatically authenticate `User` with spring security and use my `UserDetailsServie` implementation?

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I want to use spring security `UserDetailsService` together with spring data jpa `CrudRepository` interface.
Principal is represented by `User` entity which implements `UserDetails`:

```
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String username;
    private String password;

    //other methods of UserDetails
```

I have spring-security.xml config file:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <authentication-manager>
        <!-- refers to spring data repository bean org.baeldung.SpringDataAuditDemo.dao.repos.UserDao -->
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDao" />
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

It refers to bean `userDao` of type `UserDetailsService` and `CrudRepository`:

```
public interface UserDao extends CrudRepository<User, Long>, UserDetailsService {

    // @Override    
    @Query(value = "select u from User u where u.username=:username")
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(@Param("username") String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException;
}
```

Now I want to authenticate `User` object programmatically in jUnit tests.

I hope to run `UserDao.loadUserByUsername` method when authenticating `User`.
For that I wanted to  use `org.springframework.security.provisioning.UserDetailsManager` but it implements `UserDetailsService` interface as well as my `UserDao`. Therefore I got exception that two beans of same type exists!!!

Then I tried to use `UserDao` instead of `UserDetailsManager` but my `UserDao` doesn't authenticate `User`, but only loads it from db. In this case `spring-security.xml` is not needed.

How to programmatically authenticate `User` with spring security default `DaoAuthenticationProvider` and use my `UserDetailsServie` implementation?

**EDIT**

When I tried to autowire my `UserDao` with `@Qualifier` and `UserDetailsManager` without it, I got this exception :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.provisioning.UserDetailsManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1118)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:494)
... 28 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically authenticate against your custom UserDetailsService by using the AuthenticationManager. For example, the following would work in a JUnit Test:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class SecurityConfigTests {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager manager;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
        Authentication user = manager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("user", "password"));
        context.setAuthentication(user);

        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
    }
    ...
}
```

Any time  you have multiple beans of the same type you can use a [Qualifier](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) annotation. This means if you are getting an exception that two beans of the same type exists, you can specify which one  you want. For example, if you want a UserDetailsService bean by the name of userDao, you can use:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;

...

@Qualifier("userDao")
@Autowired
UserDetailsService userDao;
```

Comment: Thanks. See edit with autowire. But I can leave it as it is because it's only a demo

Comment: What does your configuration for the UserDetailsManager look like? What does your UserDetailsManager implementation look like? What does the qualifier you used look like?